# In Android, How to Handle facebook session expiration in Receiver (SDK 3.0)

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook sdk 3.0.

I'd like to use Facebook Session in the Receiver.
but what could I do if the session is expired?

Comment: To expand the question: 
What happens when we use the `Session`, but it expires? The API documentation says that the Android SDK will auto-renew the session, but, it will expire if the user changes passwords or revokes the application.

How is the expiration returned to the developer?

If it is in a `Receiver`, then there is no UI - how do we produce the login?

Comment: Also, to make it clear, I'm looking for a user login, not an app login. (I was not aware of app logins earlier.)

Answer (score 2):

The SDK is designed to be used a bit differently than what you are trying to do here. You don't need to handle the `Session` object states yourself at all. Have a look at the [Scrumptious tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/).

In it's authentication section, it is shown clearly how to handle session state changes.

Basically, facebook provides you with a bunch of **UI lifecycle helper classes** that you need to include wherever you need facebook functionality in your app. These helpers will determine if session is active, expired etc and call a method `onSessionStateChanged()` whenever there is a change in the session state.

All you need to do is perform simple checks in this method and redirect the user appropriately. For example, if the session has expired you can just redirect the user to a login page where there will a facebook login button (this button is provided by facebook in the SDK and it handles authentication flow for you. It will ask the user for permissions, authenticate the session etc without you needing to do anything).

Work through the tutorial once and I'm sure you'll have a much better understanding. Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no UI lifecycle helper class for a broadcast receiver (as shared by the original poster) - does that mean the checking should not be done here?

Comment: You can check. But the auth flow was not designed to be done inside a receiver. The use case for a developer handling authentication in receivers is pretty low. I'm sure you can poke around the SDK, find the methods used the lifecycle helpers and use those to handle everything yourself in a receiver. But this will be a big hack and will be pretty unstable. You're better off using it as intended since facebook will have tested it well for the intended usage. One idea is to check if a session has expired and launch your login activity again letting the facebook login button handle the auth flow.

Comment: Thanks. So this is the right thing to do (even if it doesn't answer the question as stated.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/GraphApiSample/src/com/facebook/samples/graphapi/GraphApiSampleActivity.java#L136-L142

```
private Session createSession() {
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
    }
    return activeSession;
}
```

This validates if session is active or not, if not - create a new one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll validate this on my dev machine.

Come to think of it, Receiver would probably work since it's running on the UI thread. Running on a raw Thread or an AsyncTask might be a problem?

Comment: No. I don't think running in non-UI thread would be an issue.

Comment: definitely there will be issue if you run this from any background thread.

Comment: Hmm... Noticed Session.Builder(this) :(

Comment: Meaning - `this` in this example is needed to pass an `Activity`. In a receiver, `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` will pass in the context which may be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found that facebook developer site said the following：

App access tokens can be generated for Facebook Apps. Generate app access tokens with a different login flow than the other tokens; this can be done in code.

This type of token is useful to modify app settings, create and manage test users or read App Insights data. You can use app tokens to publish or delete content on behalf of a user who gave your app permissions. For example, if a user granted your app publish_stream permissions, your app can use an app access token to publish a status update on their behalf.

> App tokens do not expire unless the App Secret is reset. App access tokens are unique to each app.

[source web page about access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)

so, It seems that we don't have to handle this.
If you want, you can show a message at notification bar when the token is expired due to some problem.

Comment: Sorry no, I'm not looking for app logins.

Answer (score 0):

In facebook android sdk 3.0, if session is expired than you need to re-open the session  with existing token. This you can do from other than activities (ui thread context) also.

For re-opening the expired session

```
public void openSession(Context context)
{
    Looper.prepare()
    Session session = new Session(context, APP_ID, null, true);
    session.openWithImportedAccessToken(accessToken, new Date(tokenExpiryTime), new Date(tokenExpiryTime), AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION, Arrays.asList(APP_PERMISSIONS), null);
    Looper.loop()
}
```

Please read on looper.prepare & loop mechanism before implementing this.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: 

I can re-open the session with an existing token using this `openWithImportedAccessToken` that you stated here. Since this example is not a UI thread context, I need the `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`. (as compared to in a UI thread, there these are not needed.)

Is this correct?

Comment: yah openWithImportedAccessToken is supposed to be called from ui thread as it internally uses a async task. If you are calling this from ui thread or activity than definitely you don't need  to use looper else you have to.